# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - Node/Mongoose/Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am working on an fantasy soccer app for my friends and I, but I am getting this age old error and it doesn't seem like any of the other questions answered on here really fit my situation.  In the first block of code below, the `console.log` is returning the correct data, so I am very certain that the `res.json(populatedClub)` should be working just fine.  I cannot find anywhere else in my code that is triggering another `res.send()` or `res.json()` in this chain of events.

Is anybody else able to see what I am not?

My route:

```
fantasyClubRouter.get('/:userId', 
  (req, res) => {
    FantasyClub
    .findOne({manager: req.params.userId})
    .populate({
      path: 'manager',
      model: 'User'
    })
    .exec((error, populatedClub) => {
      if (error) {
        return () => {throw new Error(error)};
      }
      console.log('populatedClub:', populatedClub);
      res.json(populatedClub);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw new Error(error);
    });
  }
);
```

The error stack:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:471:11)
     at ServerResponse.header (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
     at ServerResponse.send (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
     at ServerResponse.json (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
     at FantasyClub.findOne.populate.exec (/home/ubuntu/workspace/server/fantasyClub-routes.js:18:11)
     at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4187:16
     at (anonymous function).call (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3128:7)
     at process.nextTick (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2019:28)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
 Emitted 'error' event at:
     at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4189:13
     at (anonymous function).call (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3128:7)
     at process.nextTick (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2019:28)
     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Comment: Your question includes a lot of irrelevant information. Try to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JemiSalo: edited

Comment: Why are you returning a function inside `if (error)`? Doesn't make sense to me. You could just `throw error` or pass it to next middleware `next(error)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I had done wrong, and it was so simple that I'm almost embarrassed to admit it, but here it goes.

I updated from an older version of Mongoose and forgot to update my code accordingly.  Always make sure your code matches what the docs say for the version of the library you are using.

This is the working code:

`fantasyClubRouter.get('/:userId', 
  (req, res) => {
    FantasyClub
    .findOne({manager: req.params.userId})
    .populate({
      path: 'manager',
      model: 'User'
    })
    .then(populatedClub => {
      res.json(populatedClub);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw new Error(error);
    });
  }
);`